# How to add a String with a loop

Tags: java

Update 3: solved, thank you

Update 2: ok now I am really close but it isn't printing Tails

Update I dont want to use StringBuilder as I havn't learned about that concept. I cannot figure out what is wrong and how I add one to r

Hello I am trying to figure out how to do an assignment that asked for an int for user input and would generate a number of coin flips in String form resulting in a pattern of HHTHTHTTTHHHH etc depending on what input the user chose.

Final update solved:

```
public class Stringaddition{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
System.out.println(coinflip(8));
}

public static String coinflip(int a){
String r ="";
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
    int coin = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
    if (coin == 0) {
        String one = "T";
    r+=one;
    } 
    else if (coin == 1){
        String one = "H";
    r +=one;
}

}
return r;
}


}
```

Comment: `.=` is not an operator in java.

Comment: += doesn't work either

Comment: `String r += one;` is saying, create the string `r` and assign it to `r + one`. `r` hasn't yet been defined so you can't `+=` with it.

Comment: Because you replace `r` everytime through the loop. use a StringBuilder

Comment: The return statement should also be outside of the loop

Comment: Indent your code, and the error will be much more visible (and the code much more readable, of course). You make your own life difficult by not indenting your code.

Comment: How do I initialize r, it says error: variable r might not have been initialized
  return r;

Comment: @Nick Now that I indented your code correctly can you see what the issue is?

Comment: No I am trying to figure out how to initialize r and have that not interfere with the return statement being outside of the loop and not knowing what the variable r is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare an empty string outside of the loop, and add inside the loop. `+=` is also less efficient than a StringBuilder, so here is that solution

```
public static String coinflip(int a){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        int coin = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
        sb.append(coin == 0 ? "T" : "H");  // like an if-else 
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is an assignment for you, I won't write the whole program, here is a tip to add different strings together though:

```
String one = "H"
String r = "";

r += one; // basically "" + "H" = "H"
System.out.println(r); // will print out "H"
```

You can also use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Stringaddition{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
System.out.println(coinflip(8));
}

public static String coinflip(int a){
String r ="";
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
    int coin = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
    if (coin == 0) {
        String one = "T";
    r+=one;
    } 
    else if (coin == 1){
        String one = "H";
    r +=one;
}

}
return r;
}


}
```

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS